# REST API response when server receives extra not required data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, validation, http-error

While implementing REST APIs, validation is done of the request body received by the server.

What if some extra information which is not required (as well as not specified in REST API spec) comes in the form of JSON attributes and it's found during validation. In this case, what should the server do? Ignore extra data and send a response as a success or error response is preferred usually?

If error response suits best when `HTTP error status` most compatible in this case?

An example is given below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "user",
        "attributes": {
            "firstName": "Kazi Mahbubur",
            "lastName": "Rahman",
            "age": 30,
            "x": "x",
            "y": "y",
            "z": "z",
        }
    }
}
```

In above request body (JSON type), the x, y, z attributes are not required according to REST API spec.

Comment: Do you use Date Transfer object classes?

Comment: @DumiduUdayanga Right now I am convinced to use DTO for each req and res. But having difficulty making DTO classes as the request/response format is complex enough. For example, nested objects one after one, same DTO but different types of validation in different requests. Anyway, what is relation between DTO classes and my question?

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, what should the server do? Ignore extra data and send a response as a success or error response is preferred usually?

You'll want to look into prior art in XML, especially concepts like [must-ignore](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/10/27/extend.html).

The short version: you need to think about what you want to have happen when a version 1 client tries to talk to a version 2 server, or when a version 2 client tries to talk to a version 1 server (aka forward and backward compatibility).

The world wide web, for example, has been going for thirty years now; it does that, to a large degree, because the standards (HTTP, HTML, URI) have been constrained to evolve in ways that support compatibility.

For example, take a quick read at what Roy Fielding wrote about [Host](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_2_1)

> One of the worst mistakes in the early HTTP design was the decision not to send the complete URI that is the target of a request message....

Now consider: Fielding published this passage 20 years ago, and we *still haven't changed the way it works*.  HTTP messages, for the most part, have the same semantics that they did in 1996 when [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) was released.

> If error response suits best when HTTP error status most compatible in this case?

*If* you decide that an unrecognized schema should not be permitted, then you'll want to choose meta data that accurately reflects that.

[RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2), which defines the semantics for [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2), includes a pretty good decision tree

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.